# VBA/General - Getting a reference to the object that other objects are contained in

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a question for coding in VBA but I guess it also extends into basic programming procedure.

Im doing some stuff for a business, the business has different sections and each section has a list of jobs they need to do, each job has a list of tasks. Each section has a team of technicians that do jobs.

So I have coded a Section object that contains an array of technician objects and also an array of job objects, each job object has an array of task objects.

There are 4 or 5 sections so there are as many Section objects.

Is there an elegant way for a job object in the array to get a reference to what section object it happens to be sitting in and then be able to access the correct technician array?

Comment: Can you post the code for the Section class?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 obvious ways (but there are many others). In the examples below I have assumed 3 classes: `cSection`, `cJobs` and `cTechnicians`.

### 1. Create a `.Parent` property

Define a `Parent` property in each of your sub-classes which stores a reference to your `Section` class, like this, for example in your `cJob` class:

```
Public Parent As cSection
```

And your module would define the property like so:

```
Dim sect as cSection
Dim job as cJobs

set sect = new cSection
set job = new cJobs
set job.Parent = sect
```

This type of technique is useful if you have no means of accessing your `section` objects and only have the `job` object.

### 2. Only access sub-classes from your `section` class

Pass your job and technician arrays into the appropriate `section` class. Then simply access everything you need from that parent class. This would be a better way to go if you have a reference to the relevant `section` class. `cSection` might look like this:

```
Private mJobList() As cJobs
Private mTechList() As cTechnicians
Public Property Get JobList()
    JobList = mJobList
End Property
Public Property Get TechList()
    TechList = mTechList
End Property
```

and your module could be like this:

```
Dim sect As cSection
Dim job() As cJobs
Dim tech() As cTechnicians

Set sect = New cSection
job = sect.JobList
tech = sect.TechList
```

### 3. Create a map of section indexes to arrays

You could have a list of the sub-classes in some form of key list. A collection would be the most obvious but the example below is just a simple array. This technique can be useful if you only have the key/index to access your objects:

```
Dim parentMap(5) As Variant
Dim mapItems(1) As Variant
Dim jobs(5) As cJobs
Dim techs(5) As cTechnicians

mapItems(0) = jobs
mapItems(1) = techs
parentMap(0) = mapItems
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do something like this:

Have a class called cSection and a class called cJobs

In the cJobs have a private variable called pMySection and some sort of function like this - 

Public Sub setSection(ByRef inSection as cSection)

    pMySection = inSecton

End Sub

And then in the section class have something like-

Dim testJob as cJob
testJob = New cJob

testJob.setSection(This)

Basically can I set a reference to a class to the other class?